# Zooming in proteced sheet

Tags: excel, vba

Currently on my excel documents I have it coded so that when you click on these designated cells the screen view zooms into the cell, making it more readable. Now when I protect the sheet and use the cell I get the error code - Runtime Error '1004'

I need to protect the sheet whilst still being able to get the screen to zoom into my designated cells, any advice?

Current Code-

```
Private Sub Worksheet_SelectionChange(ByVal Target As Range)
With Range("B5000")
    If Not Intersect(Target, Range("B8:B5000")) Is Nothing Then
        If .Value <> "zoomed" Then
            ActiveWindow.Zoom = 100
            .Value = "zoomed"
        End If
    ElseIf .Value = "zoomed" Then
        ActiveWindow.Zoom = 60
        .ClearContents
    End If
End With
```

What coding do I require for this to work and where do I add this within the current code?

Comment: Look up protection with `UserInterfaceOnly:=True`. Or, unprotect programmatically and then reapply the protection.

Comment: You cannot update a protected sheet, so your `.Value = "zoomed"` and `.ClearContents` lines will fail unless you work around it by using something like the suggestions from @BigBen, or check the ActiveWindow.Zoom value directly instead of using text in a cell. You could also leave some cells unprotected, like B5000.